# RSpec. Rails 3.2. Instance variable checking. Behavior testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, capybara

I have a question with RSpec testing. I am using FactoryGirl, Capybara 2.* and trying to testing my website behavior.

Scenario of testing:
User clicking on sign_in button (devise controller), he is redirected to root_path (managed by MyController). After his redirection before_filter :setup_params should assign to @app variable (in action :find_apps in MyController) some values. I would like to ensure that @app is not nil and that values were assigned.

here is my sign_in_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper.rb"
require "mymodel.rb"

describe MyContoller, :type => :feature do

  before do
    visit '/users/sign_in'
  end

  it "Shall redirect to user and ensure that @app is not nil" do

    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user_monit)
    fill_in "user[email]", with: user.email
    fill_in "user[password]", with: user.password

    #expect {click_button "Sign in"}.to change {@myapp}.from(nil)
    click_button "Sign in"

    get :find_apps
    assigns(:myapp).should_not be_nil

  end
end
```

require section in my spec_helper.rb

```
 require 'rspec/rails'
 require 'rspec/autorun'
 require 'capybara/rails'
 require 'capybara/rspec'
 require 'mocha/setup'
 require 'factory_girl'
 ....
 config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature
```

I have got several mistakes:

```
1) result should have changed, but is still nil
2) bad argument error for get :find_apps (ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create User before you can login so :

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_monit)
```

second issue you can resolve adding normal uri instead :find_apps the same like you make in before block

Comment: Thanks, but then I have got ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Error record invalid. When I use FactoryGirl.build i can pass any test with redirection - " assert has_selector? 'table#admin-credit-application' " returns true after click_button "Sign in"

Comment: SO if you can't create :user_monit maybe someting with your factory isn't good.

Comment: it's controller test not acceptance so you can test like hire:
[link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec))
if you want cceptance test with Capybara you can find help hire:
[link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Adeptus, I wil try to follow your advice